# How do I move a linked file on Unix?

Tags: unix, symbolic-link

I have a bunch of files in one directory and links to each one of those files in another directory. So `ls -l` looks something like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rembol rembol   89 Jan 25 10:00 copyright.txt -> /home/rembol/solr/target/deploy/data/core/copyright.txt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rembol rembol   92 Jan 25 10:00 jar-versions.xml -> /home/rembol/solr/target/deploy/data/core/jar-versions.xml
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rembol rembol   85 Jan 25 10:00 lgpl.html -> /home/rembol/solr/target/deploy/data/core/lgpl.html
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rembol rembol   79 Jan 25 10:00 lib -> /home/rembol/solr/target/deploy/data/core/lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rembol rembol   87 Jan 25 10:00 readme.html -> /home/rembol/solr/target/deploy/data/core/readme.html
drwxr-xr-x 3 rembol rembol 4096 Jan 25 10:00 server
drwxr-xr-x 2 rembol rembol 4096 Jan 25 10:00 startup
```

Now I want to move those linked files from `/home/rembol/solr/target/deploy` to `/home/rembol/output/`. If I do that my simply calling `mv`, links will break. I don't want to re-link each file separately, cause there are hundreds of them (they are generated automatically).

Is there some clever way to move linked files, rather than writing a script that unlinks, moves and relinks recursively for each file in each subdirectory?

Answer (score 4):

The short version is that `mv` can't do this. You'll need to retarget the links on your own. I was going to offer a suggestion on how to do this, but there's already a really good answer to a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/how-can-i-relink-a-lot-of-broken-symlinks#18365) posted over on the Unix/Linux site.